# Modal stops working when click outside the container

Tags: javascript

Modal is working already, when you click the button it opens the modal and when you click x button, it closes the modal, however, I try to add 
`const mainWrapper = document.querySelector(".modal-main-wrapper");` and the logic.

The reason I add it is because when I click the "container or outside the modal", it would close, but it seems my modal stops working.

So what's wrong with it? I tried to target it to body as well,
 `const closeBody = document.querySelector("body");`, but still not working as well.

```js
const buttonClick = document.querySelector(".button-click");
const modalWrapper = document.querySelector(".modal-wrapper");

buttonClick.addEventListener("click", _ => {
  modalWrapper.classList.add("modal-show");
})

const buttonClose = document.querySelector(".modal-button-close");

buttonClose.addEventListener("click", _ => {
  modalWrapper.classList.remove("modal-show");
})

//The problem starts from here
const mainWrapper = document.querySelector(".modal-main-wrapper");

mainWrapper.addEventListener("click", _ => {
  modalWrapper.classList.remove("modal-show");
})
```

```css
.button-click {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.modal-wrapper {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.modal-wrapper.modal-show {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="modal-main-wrapper">
    <button class="button-click">Click me!</button>

    <div class="modal-wrapper">
      <button class="modal-button-close">x</button>
      <p>Hello</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click the button it also triggers click on the parent `modal-main-wrapper`. To prevent this you should use [**Event.stopPropagation()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

> **stopPropagation()**: method of the Event interface **prevents further propagation of the current event** in the capturing and bubbling phases

```js
const buttonClick = document.querySelector(".button-click");
const modalWrapper = document.querySelector(".modal-wrapper");

buttonClick.addEventListener("mousedown", _ => {
  console.log("clicked")
  modalWrapper.classList.add("modal-show");
  console.log(modalWrapper.outerHTML)
  _.stopPropagation()
})

const buttonClose = document.querySelector(".modal-button-close");

buttonClose.addEventListener("click", _ => {
  modalWrapper.classList.remove("modal-show");
  _.stopPropagation(); 
})

//The problem starts from here
const mainWrapper = document.querySelector(".modal-main-wrapper");

mainWrapper.addEventListener("mousedown", _ => {
  console.log('clicked');
  modalWrapper.classList.remove("modal-show");
})
```

```css
.button-click {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.modal-wrapper {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.modal-show {
  visibility: visible !important;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="modal-main-wrapper">
    <button class="button-click">Click me!</button>

    <div class="modal-wrapper">
      <button class="modal-button-close">x</button>
      <p>Hello</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working, I actually added: stopPropagation() but didn't work because I only add it on mainWrapper.addEventListener, I didn't put it under buttonClose and buttonClick listener. I'm wondering why do I need to add the stopPropagation in every listener? When I don't have the mainWrapper listener, it was working without adding the stopPropagation() on buttonClose and buttonClick listener.

Comment: When you will click any child the click event of parent will also trigger.To stop event bubbling you need to use **event.stopPropagation**